# SharePoint Designer: Append Changes to Existing Text in Email

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

When my list workflow triggers an email, the body of the email contains an existing text field that is set to multiple lines and “Append Changes to Existing Text.”  Currently this field only displays the last entered text and not previous entries too, like my InfoPath form does.

I can’t find anything on the internet that tells me how to show all entries. Is there a way to do this in SharePoint Designer 2010 or 2013?

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround to the problem you are having.

You might have to create a new column in the list without the "Append Changes to Existing Text" option enabled to capture changes happening to the multiline textbox and show that textbox in the workflow email.

Step by step procedure would be:

1. Create a workflow which gets triggered every time the multiline textbox changes.
2. Create an action in the workflow which copies any text entered in the multiline textbox into the newly created non-appended textbox.
3. Use that text box in the previously defined workflow email so that full history of the multiline textbox gets showed.

Hope this explains clearly.

Comment: I’m not familiar with a hidden variable in the list.  Is this created in designer, outside of a workflow, or in SharePoint?  Thank you.

Comment: It's just creating an extra column in the list and make it non visible for general users. Go to the list-->advanced settings and select yes on allow management of content type. After that click on any existing column you want to hide and choose hidden from the options. If you open the list you will find that that column is not visible in both new and edit forms. You can use that hidden column to store values and use it later in workflow mail. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you.  So every time a new entry is made in the multiline enhanced rich text field, the variable would copy and store that text in the hidden field?  Would the hidden field contain the same properties but without the “Append Changes to Existing Text?"  Using these settings, the text overides previous stored text in the hidden field. Adding Append Changes did not work either.  Sorry, I'm missing something.

Comment: I have edited the answer to explain the procedure. Please let me know if that clarifies the scenario.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit dim but in step 2, when text is copied to the new textbox, won't it overwrite any previous text stored there?  This item will be updated by multiple people over a period of time and I need to capture all the latest comments in an email.  Thanks.

Comment: You will be appending the text into the non-appended textbox through workflow. Say for an example: Currently the textbox has "String A". In the multiline textbox user enters text "String B". Since the workflow listens to the multiline textbox changes, it will be triggered and as you can always get the last entered text from the multiline textBox you will be getting the text "String B" and append it with the existing text "String A". So once the workflow finishes the non-appended textbox will look like "String A String B" which you will be using whichever you want.